# Title slide text formatting does not apply when adding a custom background image

Tags: css, r, styles, r-markdown

I have the following css to edit the title slide. I am trying to add a background image and position the title and change the font colors for both the title and author/date text.

```
---
title: "Mechanical Rebar Couplers in<br>Column Plastic Hinge Zones"
author: "Maral Dorri"
date: "February 16, 2021"
output:
  ioslides_presentation:
    incremental: true
    widescreen: true
    smaller: true
    slide_level: 1
    fig_caption: true
    self_contained: true
    transition: "faster"
---


<style>
body {
  text-align: justify}
h2 { 
  color: #427cb3;
  text-decoration: underline}
h3 { 
  color: #427cb3;
slides > slide {
  background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #ffffff 85%, #ffffff);
  background-color: white;
  color: #4a4a54}
slides > slide.title-slide hgroup h1 {
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 40pt;
      color: white;
      text-align: right;
      top: 50%}
slides > slide.title-slide {
  text-align: left;
  color: #4a4a54;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16pt;
  background-image: url(TFHRC.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%}
</style>
```

The text formats stopped working when I added the background image as shown in the picture:

[image]

**EDIT:**

I was able to get the color and justification fixed by changing the YAML. But I can still not position the title when it needs to go. The `top: 50%;` does nothing!

```
---
title: "<right>Mechanical Rebar Couplers in<br>Column Plastic Hinge Zones</right>"
author: "Maral Dorri"
date: "February 16, 2021"
output:
  ioslides_presentation:
    incremental: true
    widescreen: true
   smaller: true
    slide_level: 1
    fig_caption: true
    self_contained: true
    transition: "faster"
---

<style>
slides > slide {
  background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #ffffff 85%, #ffffff);
  background-color: white;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 20pt;}
slides > slide hgroup h2 { 
  color: #427cb3;
  font-weight: bold}
slides > slide.title-slide {
  background-image: url('TFHRC.jpg');
  background-size: 100% 100%}
slides > slide.title-slide hgroup h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 35pt;
  color: black;
  text-align: right;}
slides > slide.title-slide p {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;}
</style>
```

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to use ```xaringan``` (https://github.com/yihui/xaringan)

Comment: What about `background-image: url('TFHRC.jpg')`?

Comment: adding the '' didnt make a difference @bttomio

Comment: Yes, I see. It seems to be a problem with h3 { color: #427cb3;. When it is removed, the image appears.

Comment: @bttomio I dont have an issue getting the image, I cant position the title...

Comment: I get the right title format with your code. Nevertheless, the picture does not show (I am using a local image file).

Answer (score 0):

By removing some parts of your CSS edit, it renders the title page with the image and the correct title format. I also added a missing `}` at the end of `h3`.

Code removed:

```
slides > slide.title-slide hgroup h1 {
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 40pt;
      color: white;
      text-align: right;
      top: 50%}
```

New code:

```
---
title: "Mechanical Rebar Couplers in<br>Column Plastic Hinge Zones"
author: "Maral Dorri"
date: "February 16, 2021"
output:
  ioslides_presentation:
    incremental: true
    widescreen: true
    smaller: true
    slide_level: 1
    fig_caption: true
    self_contained: true
    transition: "faster"
---

<style>
body {
  text-align: justify}
h2 { 
  color: #427cb3;
  text-decoration: underline}
h3 { 
  color: #427cb3;}
slides > slide {
  background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #ffffff 85%, #ffffff);
  background-color: white;
  color: #4a4a54}
slides > slide.title-slide {
  text-align: left;
  color: #4a4a54;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16pt;
  background-image: url("https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/image-4.jpg");
  background-size: 100% 100%}
</style>
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Again, I dont have an issue getting the background, the formatting of the title is not working. In your picture, the title is not aligned left and the location is not where I want it.

Comment: Could you please provide a picture of the correct position of the title?

Comment: well, moving anywhere other the center, let's say upper-right corner. I am not able to move it at all!